# How to close DB2 and Oracle DB connection in RobotFramework

Tags: python, database, oracle, robotframework

I was trying to close an open DB2 connection for one of my automation script in robot-framework so that I can open a Oracle DB connection and perform certain task. I tried using inbuilt function provided in database library of Robot Framework for closing the connection but it is not closing the connection and giving an error:

> `AttributeError: "NoneType" object has no attribute "close"`

Close method which is written in database library of Robot-Framework is as below:

```
def disconnect_from_database(self):
    self._dbconnection.close()
```

Steps performed in my scripts are:

1. Application related validation
2. Validation in IBM DB2 after connecting
3. Disconnect IBM DB2
4. Open Oracle DB and perform certain validation

If I am removing step 3 to disconnect IBM DB2 and directly open oracle connection I am getting error during runtime as

> `RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class oracle.jdbc.driver.Oracle Driver not found`

Please note that oracle db jars are present and script is working fine when I need either DB2 or Oracle DB connection but giving above mentioned error when I need to connect to both the DBs in single script.

Can anyone help me how I can connect to both DBs without these errors?

Comment: Can you share your robot script?